# How to convert a BufferedImage to Texture?

Tags: java, graphics, textures, bufferedimage, slick2d

I am trying to convert a `BufferedImage` to a `Texture` from Slick2D.
I have tried `BufferedImageUtil.getTexture()`, but either I am using it wrong, or it's not working (returns only one brown pixel out of a 32x32 image)

How can I convert a `BufferedImage` to a `Texture`?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using it wrong, but as you do not provide any source code of your implementation I can only guess.

The syntax for [BufferedImage.get(...)](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc-util/org/newdawn/slick/util/BufferedImageUtil.html#getTexture(java.lang.String, java.awt.image.BufferedImage)) is:

```
public static Texture getTexture(java.lang.String resourceName,
                                 java.awt.image.BufferedImage resourceImage)
                          throws java.io.IOException

Parameters:
  resourceName - The location of the resource to load
  resourceImage - The BufferedImage we are converting
Returns:
  The loaded texture
```

I used this once when setting up my own fonts and I converted the BufferedImages (resulting from a splitImage operation of a bigger image with all characters on it) to Textures. It worked just fine for me, I ignored the `resourceName` parameter though.

So this works for me:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
Texture texture = BufferedImageUtil.getTexture("", image);
```

Looking at the source code of this method, the resourceName parameter should not have any impact on the method at all.

So just try it with my example and then try to implement this in your project, if you have any troubles with that let me know in the comments and I can help you.

**See**

- http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc-util/org/newdawn/slick/util/BufferedImageUtil.html

**Edit**

There are some fundamental flaws with your code:

- (*This is why your code doesn't work at all/throws an exception*). You load the texture with `BufferedImage texture = ImageIO.read(new File(path+ "/texture.png"));` in your constructor, which does not change the texture parameter in your block but rather just creates a local unused variable. Fix this by removing the `BufferedImage` in that line.
- (Almost) everything there is static. That makes no sense, as each block for example can have its own textures and parameters.
- Please obey the Java naming conventions. Class names are upper camel case (`MyClass`), variable names lower camel case (`myVariable`), methods are lower camel case (`myMethod`), constants are upper case (`MY_CONSTANT`) and packages are lower case (`mypackage`).

Comment: Okay, Im Getting some Errors.
Error: [link](http://pastebin.com/zSDXdST4)
Main Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/c0TjdJKz)
Block Class: [link](http://pastebin.com/iyw1TCdW)

Thanks.

Comment: @Zambonie I will need the line you are calling the BufferedImageUtil.getTexture(...) method. In the code you have linked the line `zambonie.reality.engine.startGame(engine.java:83)` is missing, which is the method call, please include it.

Comment: Ah, Sorry. Line 83 Is 20 In the pastebin I gave you, ill link the whole code :P
[link](http://pastebin.com/ghqFp665)

Comment: @Zambonie Because the BufferedImage you are converting is `null`. You have some fundamental flaws in your code, I will add them to my answer.

Comment: Ok, That's Fixed. But Again, I'm getting the exact same I got at the begining of this ( [link](http://i.imgur.com/Mg3BtPR.png) ), Those Dots. Its supposed to be a Full 32*32 Grass texture. Anything you may find now? Thanks.
And, Also, For #3, This is our lives, We can do anything, Doing anything with the caps in Names Really Won't Do anything bad, Like error Out.

Comment: @Zambonie I am serious mate, code really looks incredibly ugly and bad written just because of bad names. Trust me. Same with normal English btw ;)

Comment: I know, But English isn't as Important as Java, isn't It.
Anyway beside that, I Still Can't Find out my Texture Problem..

Comment: @Zambonie Ignorance against the conventions won't help you getting answers. Have you tried what I suggested in my editted answer? And just saying, on StackOverflow posts with a lack of proper English (in text and code) tend to attract more downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Load texture:

Texture texture;
texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/image.png")));

If it doesn't fix your problem, then it is something wrong with the way you bind it.

Comment: To be Honest, All your really telling me is How to load a Image, at the way Im seeing this.
I need to **convert a bufferedImage into a Texture**
Unless your telling me to save the BufferedImage and loading it as a Texture, Thats Going to be to slow for me, Im trying to make a Game, That atleast has decent FPS

Comment: Post your code where you load your texture as well as where you use it.